# jquery page refresh not working in firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, page-refresh

My Jquery page refresh script not working in Firefox but chrome is fine .

```
window.onresize = function(){ location.reload(); }
```

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/oLaf08r8/2/

Comment: Have you tried forcing it ? location.reload(true)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resize event is firing - its your reload that is failing.

You could try:

```
window.onresize = function(){ 
console.log("resize event fired");
window.location = window.location;
}
```

which will work in Firefox and Chrome I believe

Comment: working but firefox shows "{"error": "Please use POST request"}"

Comment: I think that is just the way jsfiddle processes the page - its warning you that there is POST data associated with the page taht a GET request such as this will lose. e.g. Codepen is fine http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DaELm

Comment: working but the issue is loading  not stopping...it working continuously :(

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to debounce it a little, e.g:

```
window.onresize = function () {
    clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    this.timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        location.reload();
    }, 0);
};
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fffpogt5/)

That's said, seems weird behaviour to reload page on each resize.

Comment: @Krish maybe you would have better to explain why would you need to reload page on window resize. Quite sure this is a XY problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem